# Will changing publisher name in google play show in apps already in the appstore

Tags: android, publish

I have 3 apps already in google play. I would like to change the publisher name from my name to my company name. I have read previous discussions on how to change the name in the developer console.

My question is, after changing he name do I have to re-sign the app,  get a new certificate, make any changes to the binaries or republish the apps? The Google support doc seems to suggest I may need to transfer to a different developer account which may involve all these steps.

I'm hoping that is not the case, all I need to change is  the publisher name (only) - all the other credentials will be the same. I'm hoping the name change will  propagate to the 3 apps without having to change anything and any future updates will get the appropriate notification etc. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you don't have to. You can simply change the name, without doing anything else.

Comment: Thanks very much eric247 for responding. But I need firm confirmation, so I don't create problems for my users.